# enthought gdal/ogr not built with GEOS?

Tags: enthought

I'm using the academic version of enthought python for Windows. Most of ogr works, but not geometry methods like geometry.Buffer() or predicates like geometry1.crosses(geometry2).  According to this:

http://gdal.org/python/osgeo.ogr.Geometry-class.html#Crosses

ogr needs to have been built with GEOS. Has anybody got these methods to work with Enthought? If not, can you suggest a Windows python binary where these are working?

thanks,
jim

Answer (score 0):

Correct, there are many possible build configurations of GDAL/OGR, and geos is not currently supported by Enthought's build configuration. We will consider adding it in a future build. Meanwhile, FYI, GEOS operations are fully supported in the powerful and popular Shapely package which is included in the Enthought repository.

Comment: I hope you do add this.  Especially for students, fewer modules is better. Many thanks!