# GDAL/OGR now built with geos?

Tags: enthought, gdal, ogr

Back in 2014 Enthought's build of GDAL/OGR was missing important functionality.  In October of that year John from Enthought wrote:

"Correct, there are many possible build configurations of GDAL/OGR, and geos is not currently supported by Enthought's build configuration. We will consider adding it in a future build. "

Did this happen? For example, can we now use OGR's buffer method?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, not yet, not much apparent demand relative to other packages.

Reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26596496/1988991